# Javascript Regex to replace brackets with content inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to replace brackets with other content, in this case, a div tag..

So, the text:

```
This is a [sample] text
```

Would become:

```
This is a <div>sample</div> text
```

The problem is, it should only replace when both brackets are found, and keep the content inside. If only one bracket is found, it should ignore it..

So

```
This is a [sample text
```

or

```
This is a ] sample text
```

Both would remain as is.

Also it should match more than one occurence, so:

```
This [is] a [sample] [text]
```

Would become

```
This <div>is</div> a <div>sample</div> <div>text</div>
```

And one last thing, it should remove (or at least ignore) nested brackets, so

```
This [[is a ] sample [[[ tag]]]
```

Would become

```
This <div>is a</div> sample <div> tag </div>
```

This is what I got until now:

```
function highlightWords(string){
    return string.replace(/(.*)\[+(.+)\]+(.*)/,"$1<div>$2</div>$3");
}
```

It works in simple cases, but won't get multiple occurences and won't remove other tags. Any regex masters around?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3bfa6 - but not the nested one

Comment: Seems exactly a job for positive look-aheads

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to describe content before and after brackets. You must forbid brackets in the content description, so use `[^\][]+` instead of `.+`. Don't forget to add `g` for a global replacement:

```
function highlightWords(string){
    return string.replace(/\[+([^\][]+)]+/g,"<div>$1</div>");
}
```

Note: you don't need to escape the closing square bracket outside a character class, it isn't a special character.

Comment: Do you mean `[^\][]` to forbid brackets (in your prose)?

Comment: What about `[a[b]]` - should result in `a<div>b</div>`[?](https://regex101.com/r/oX7uZ2/1)

Comment: @Jonny5: no, in this case the first opening bracket is seen as an orphan bracket, so the result should be: `[a<div>b</div>`